Parameterized constructor causing unexpected behavior when deserializing in Json.Net
using System;
using System.IO;

using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class PopulateTest
{
    public static void Test()
    {
        JsonSerializer serializer = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault();
        string json = "{\"Inner\":{\"Random\":\"a\",\"Value\":{\"num\":1}}}";
        Outer outer = new();

        using (StringReader reader = new(json)) 
        {
            serializer.Populate(reader, outer);
        }

        Console.Log(outer.Inner.Value.num);
    }
}

public class Outer
{
    public Outer() { }

    public Inner Inner { get; set; }
}

public class Inner
{
    [JsonConstructor]
    protected Inner(string random)
    {
        Console.Log("Inner JSON constructor");
        Random = random;
    }

    public string Random { get; }

    public Value Value { get; } = new();
}

public class Value
{
    public int num;

    public Value() => Console.Log("Value constructor");
}

Here is the code sample I'm working with.
The JSON
{
    "Inner": {
         "Random": "a",
         "Value": { "num": 1 }
    }
}

This produces the following output:
Value constructor
Value constructor
Inner JSON constructor
0

The first Value constructor is called from the Json.Net library from Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader:CreateNewObject and the second Value constructor is from the initial value.
The intended behavior is for it to populate Value rather than create a new object, and of course for outer.Inner.Value.num to be 1 after deserialization. However, when using a default constructor (removing string random as a parameter for Inner's JsonConstructor), it functions properly. The output from that is:
Value constructor
Inner JSON constructor
1


Is this a duplicate of Usage of non-default constructor breaks order of deserialization in Json.net?

@dbc It looks like it might be, in which case it's a problem with Json.NET and it isn't possible to do it the exact way I was hoping to.

Not so much a problem as a limitation.  The facts that Json.NET is a single-pass deserializer while JSON objects are unordered collections of key/value pairs means that Json.NET must deserialize all properties + constructor arguments before calling the constructor.  The only question is whether to deserialize properties to the final type or to some intermediate JToken.  They chose to deserialize to the final type, probably for performance reasons.

Anyway, is the answer there sufficient to mark this as a duplicate, or do you need a more specific answer?  That question was specifically about reference tracking, since you are not doing that you have some additional workarounds possible.

@dbc Yes I would say it can be marked as duplicate.

you should add the property [JsonConstructor] to the constructor that matches the json string being passed, with the current code you are showing it is calling the constructor with the random variable and it is being set correctly, but value and num within is not.
change the constructors like this:

    [JsonConstructor]
    public Inner(string random, Value value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Inner constructor");
        Random = random;
        Value = value;
    }

    //[JsonConstructor]
    protected Inner(string random)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Inner JSON constructor");
        Random = random;
    }

notice the change in the first constructor to accept a value object instead of count. This way your code should work

That's not the behavior I'm trying to achieve. I'm specifically trying to have it populate Value while also having a parameterized constructor.

I don't understand your idea, the first constructor is parametrized as you requested.

I'm trying to have some of the properties be parametrized while having some be populated.

The constructor of Inner class that you want only accepts "string random" and no value parameter, so the value property won't be populated
